# Как работать с OAuth в Java?

Tags: oauth, java

Нигде не могу найти примеров как работать с OAuth в java, подкиньте ссылочки или дайте пример пожалуйста.

Comment: - http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/
 - http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/example/
 - https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

Comment: Куча кода, ничего не расписано и не понятно.

Comment: А Вам какая именно java нужна? может для андроида и OAuth окажется от гугла. Это может очень сильно все поменять.

Comment: Да, для андроида, т.е просто без какой то библиотеки я не смогу работать с OAuth?
Хотелось бы самому понять работу OAuth и не использовать сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: можно написать все ручками, но Вы потратите очень много времени. Но если сильно хочется, то почитайте соответствующие документы-стандарты [OAuth](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849) и [OAuth 2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749).

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю. Это жесть конечно.

Answer (score 2):

Не существует (пока) стандартного API для работы с OAuth (хотя бы на уровне стандартизованного интерфейса) и насколько я знаю нет соответствующего JSR (Java Specification Request) - по сути это означает, что разработчик должен полагаться на внешнюю библиотеку и ее правила работы с OAuth. Каждый разработчик реализует OAuth так как удобно ему.

На текущий момент стандарт де-факто это [гуглевская](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/).

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут есть библиотеки [oauth.net](http://oauth.net/2/)